# locate a file by its full file name?

Tags: locate

When I run `locate syn`, it will return files with `syn` appearing in their file names.

How can I search for files with full name `syn`? Is `locate --regex syn$` the correct way, while `locate --regex ^syn$` isn't?

Comment: But you don't have `syn` at the beginning of the line, do you? Try `locate --regex '/syn$'`.

Answer (score 3):

The `--regex` option applies to the entire path, not just the file name. So, `locate --regex syn$` will match all files and directories whose path, including their name, ends in `syn` while `locate --regex syn$` will only match a file whose entire path is `syn` and such a file does not exist:

```
$ locate --regex ^etc$ ## returns nothing
$ locate --regex ^/etc$
/etc
```

The option you're looking for is `-b`:

```
   -b, --basename
          Match  only  the base name against the specified patterns.  This
          is the opposite of --wholename.
```

You could, therefore, do

```
locate -b --regex ^sys$
```

That will list all files and folders in `locatedb` whose name is exactly `sys`.